# Autosaving the original NSDocument to original path in real time

Tags: objective-c, swift, appkit, nsdocument

I want to achieve the same document autosaving behaviour found in the standard Notes app or Final Cut Pro X, where the document/file is automatically saved with every change and there's no `Save` main menu or other manual save controls. It has to work in real time, so every modification would trigger async document save and there's no UI for manually triggering the save, since it's needless. At the moment I do this whenever the data changes:

```
self.save(to: url, ofType: type, for: .autosaveInPlaceOperation, completionHandler: { _ in })
```

It works as expected but I'm a little struggling to comprehend if this is the optimal solution. There's already standard out of the box autosaving support, but it's meant for slightly different scenarios. Can it be used effectively in my case or is there a better approach altogether?

Comment: What about `autosave(withDelegate:didAutosave:contextInfo:)`? Or even just `updateChangeCount`?

Comment: I've played with it but having doubts about it. The document window must think it's always saved, otherwise when changes are done it will change state (close button gets that circle in the center) and will ask to save when attempted to be closed. Overriding `updateChangeCount`, triggering the `autosave(withDelegate…)` from there and immediately doing `updateChangeCount(.changeCleared)` solves that, but feels like an overkill. Isn't it? Triggering `updateChangeCount` on it's own didn't give any results at all, even with reduced `NSDocumentController` `autosavingDelay`.

Comment: "The document window must think it's always saved, otherwise when changes are done it will change state (close button gets that circle in the center) and will ask to save when attempted to be closed." Whether that happens is purely a matter of the user's choices in the General preference pane, isn't it? I don't think you're in charge of how autosaving kicks in automatically. I'm a little unclear on why you'd want to force it even against the user's will...

Comment: Not that I disagree with Matt Neuburg, who knew Cocoa before I knew how to speak… but not necessarily!

Comment: There're a few apps around that work extremely well with saving changes on the fly and not providing general preferences for that. In some cases there's no obvious document entity as such, but NSDocument architecture still helps to get things done and avoid boilerplate. In other cases not all users might be happy, agree, but it's down to developers to make the call based on best intentions. In my case it works best as described and I want to make that experience better by figuring out the optimal solution! ✌️